# java spring repositories - findBy() method using set of IDs/values

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a java spring app. It does back end stuff, offering a Restful API, all using an Oracle database.

For most resources, it follows a typical design pattern: "Controller > Service > Repository > DB".

At the repository level, when extending the JpaRepository interface, one can define a set of methods without having to provide a body, just like this:

```
public interface SurgeryRepository extends JpaRepository<Surgery, String> {

    public List<Surgery> findByPracticeNameContainingIgnoreCase(String substring); 

    public Surgery findById(String id); 

}
```

What i would like to know is how to define a method that allow me to retrieve multiple rows using a list of ids, something like:

```
public List<Surgery> findByIDs(List<String> IDs);
```

Something that should automatically map to this sort of SQL

```
SELECT * FROM SURGERIES WHERE SURGERY_ID IN ('101',102,103',104',105',106')
```

... but without having to write a native query in the java code. (and not necessarily for id, it could be for any field) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `in` keyword. `findByIdIn(Iterable<Long> ids)`. This is also explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: thanks! and: "findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages) ==>
… where x.age in ?1" for other fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
findAll(Iterable<ID> ids)
```

Method provided by JpaRepository.

Comment: Thanks! What about the exact same question when it's not an id, like a set of emails or something? is something like findByEmail(Iterable<String> emails) supposed to work automatically?

Comment: You can define this method in your repository interface and use @Query annotation where you can define your query.

Comment: and: "findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages) ==> where x.age in ?1" for other fields.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that it returns a stream? 'Stream<Surgery> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids)' returns a list wrapped in a stream, losing part of the advantage of the stream; and 'Stream<Surgery> readAll(Iterable<ID> ids)' returns a 'no property' error.

Comment: If you want to get stream you can define your own signature with `Stream` as return type. But you should use another method param type, otherwise code will not compile.

Comment: The method is (now?) called `findAllById`.